# Check if array of hashtables contains a hashtable

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, hashtable, contains

I'm collecting data from a JSON file with the cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json`. That works so far. The JSON contains an array of hashtables.

```json
[
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "jodoe",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-1"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "jodoe",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-2"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "frmark",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-1"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "frmark",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-2"
    }
]
```

Now I have another array of hashtables containing some overlapping data.

```json
[
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "jodoe",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-1"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "jodoe",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-2"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "niwellenstein",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-1"
    },
    {
        "userSamAccountName":  "niwellenstein",
        "QuotaGroup":  "AD-Group-Contoso-2"
    }
]
```

I'd like to combine them without getting duplicates.

I tried some cmdletys like `select -Unique` and `.Contains()` but it don't work like I want it to work.

Background: I got a range of AD groups. In this groups users are only allowed to be member of one group - e.g.: jodoe can be member of AD-Group-Contoso-1 or AD-Group-Contoso-2 but not to both of them. And I need to report them.
The report-file will be processed by a scheduled task which reports them to the admins. The first script runs every 20 minutes and the report-scheduled-task which processes the report-file from the first script runs once a day - so I don't want to have duplicates in my report file.

Here is my code what I tried so far:

```bsh
# Group users in list to check if user is in 2 or more Groups #
$reportDuplicates = $adUserlist |
                    group -Property userSamAccountName |
                    ? { $_.Count -gt 1 } 
# only select the group of the duplicates #
# $reportDuplicates.Group corresponds to the Json File # 
$reportDuplicates = $reportDuplicates.Group

$reportPath = "C:\\temp\\reports\\" 
$reportDuplicatesPath = $reportPath + "reportADDuplicates.json"

# Check if file already exists #
if (Test-Path $reportDuplicatesPath) {
    # load existing reports #
    $existingDuplicatesReport = Get-Content $reportDuplicatesPath |
                                ConvertFrom-Json
    $reportDuplicates.ForEach({
        if ($existingDuplicatesReport.Contains($_)) {
            $existingDuplicatesReport.Add($_)
        }
    })
    # convert to JSON and save in file #
    $existingDuplicatesReport | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $reportDuplicatesPath
} else {
    # convert to JSON and save in file #
    $reportDuplicates | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $reportDuplicatesPath
}
```

But it won't work, I got the feeling, that I can't check if an array of hashtables contains a hashtable?

If I push them all into the array and do a `select -Unique` I only get the first entry of the array of hashtables.

Comment: Hashtables are reference types, and `Contains()` will look for objects of the exact same *identity*, not objects with *similar* content. You'll have to iterate over the collection and do the comparison manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell `Select-Object` on which keys of the nested hashtables you want to establish uniqueness:

```
$arr1 = $json1 | ConvertFrom-Json
$arr2 = $json2 | ConvertFrom-Json

$arr1 + $arr2 | Select-Object -Unique 'userSamAccountName', 'QuotaGroup'
```